# Better replacement for ShowModalDialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Currently in my website, I am displaying a ShowModalDialogue to display a warning. Recently I have been asked to modify the behavior of this as belows :

Earlier behavior :

I used to just show a warning message. The user can click OK or Close button of the dialogue box to proceed.

New behavior :

I have been asked to insert a text box in the same ShowModalDialogue. Now the user has to insert his initials before clicking OK button. Also now he can not close the dialogue by clicking Close button also. If he tries to close the dialogue by clicking either on Close button or OK button while text box is empty, same pop up has to open with warning. But the trouble is after closing the warning message dialogue is shifted randomly on screen even though its properties have been modified such that it will not move.

Now I have been asked to replace this ShowModalDialogue by something better. 
I have two suggestions : 1. CSS div Popup 2. Ajax-control ModalPopup. 
Which one of them is better? 
Is there anything else which can be used instead that I can use?

My major concerns are good look and easy to handle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I prefer jQuery UI Dialog *as a base* (I apply the plugin, "fix" the jQuery UI centric DOM and move on) - while I don't like how it is by default, the base it provides *just works correctly* for things like Tab Control and content sizing and can be hacked (modified) sufficiently from the outside so that it remains flexible. (I use DurandalJS to actually host the dialog content - via the "show modal view" support - which avoids having to shove markup into JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

Wanna try qTip2? This one got lots of options for you.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#dialogues

Comment: Thanks for reply and This sounds good. Unfortunately my site is a commercial. Hence I can not use any third party plugins except jquery source or AJAXControlToolkit. Can you suggest something else please?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it with **jquery UI**

```
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
                bValid =  $("#d-form").valid();
                if (bValid ){
                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" +  $( "#name" ).val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + $( "#email" ).val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + $( "#password" ).val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/536fm/6/)

Comment: Thanks. But can its behavior made like the user can not close it with Close button of the window or with empty text boxes?

Comment: In close function you can do your validations and add retrun statement  if validation fails.Making any sense ?

Comment: Yes. And I guess I will have to add same code in Cancel Function too,right?